# Cordova inappbrowser orientation

Tags: javascript, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an Cordova application that is locked in landscape orientation via the config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

The application opens a document in an new inappbrowser window. That window is then also in landscape. Now I was wondering wether it is possible (and how) to make that window autorotate instead of being fixed like the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this plugin

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

You can lock and unlock the screen rotation when you want. Just lock the orientation in the app init, unlock when the inappbrowser is opened, and lock it again when is closed

Comment: I will try this approach, if it works i will accept your answer. But thanks for the great suggestion anyway did not think about using that plugin in that way (i knew that plugin existed :) ).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tell you that I had a similar problem with a locked app, that have a view that needs to be autorrotative, and works like a charm ;)